# "LEFT JOIN AND" and "LEFT JOIN WHERE" which is better

Tags: mysql

**orders**

```
id
name
```

**order_details**

```
id
name
type
order_id
```

If I want to count order details which type is 1, which sql statement is better and more efficient

**A**

```
SELECT
    `orders`.`name`
FROM
    `orders`
LEFT JOIN `order_details` ON `order_details`.`order_id` = `order`.`order_id`
WHERE
    `order_details`.`type` = 1
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
```

**B**

```
SELECT
    `orders`.`name`
FROM
    `orders`
LEFT JOIN `order_details` ON `order_details`.`order_id` = `order`.`order_id` AND `order_detail`.`type` = 1
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the condition into your `where` clause will turn the `left  join` into an `inner join`.

Why? Because you filter the data in the `where` clause. But in the `on` condition of a join you only define what to join.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to use a `LEFT JOIN` is so that the result will include rows from the first table that have no match in the second table. For this reason, you have to put all the criteria on the second table into the `ON` clause. If you put it into the `WHERE` clause, it will filter out all the rows with no match, because in these rows `order_details.type` will be `NULL`, is obviously not `= 1`.

In addition, if you're counting matches, you need to use `IFNULL(COUNT(order_details.someColumn), 0)` rather than `COUNT(*)`. If you use `COUNT(*)` you'll get `1` for the rows with no match, because there's still a row in the results with data from `orders` and `NULL`s in all the `order_details` columns. By counting a column in the `order_details` table, the null values will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

I think its no matter you use “LEFT JOIN AND” and “LEFT JOIN WHERE"

For bulk data, You must have proper indexing to get result faster.